# How c++ new statement work?

Tags: c++

Why the last "cout" line always output "16" ??
On my machine, sizeof(int) is 4.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int *pint1 = new int;
  int *pint2 = new int;
  cout<<pint1 <<endl;
  cout<<pint2 <<endl;

  cout<<(int)pint2 - (int)pint1 <<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot really make any assumptions about the location of `pint1` and `pint2` on the stack (the pointers *are* stack allocated but the things they point to are allocated on the heap) as it's not specified by the C++ standard. They certainly do not have to be in contiguous memory.

For example, using pointer arithmetic `pint1 + 1` does **not**, in general, land you on `pint2`.

Pointer arithmetic could be used if you'd written `int* pint = new int[2];`. Then, `pint + 1` points to the second element.

To keep things standard, using

```
 cout << (std::ptrdiff_t)(pint2 - pint1) << endl;
```

would be preferred, where I'm using `(std::ptrdiff_t)` explicitly. The way you've currently written it could give you *undefined behaviour* if you have a 32 bit `int` on a 64 bit architecture (e.g. Win64, MSVC).

(And don't forget to `delete` the allocated memory).

Comment: `pint1` and `pint2` aren't on the stack. They are heap allocated.

Comment: That's what I meant to say, sorry. But the example code is printing out the difference of the values of the pointers and they point to heap allocated objects.

Comment: I concur. In fact to print out the dereferenced values would be *undefined behaviour* as the data are not initialised.

Comment: The expression `pint2 - pint1` is itself _undefined behavior_. You can't subtract two unrelated pointers; § 5.7 para 6 "Unless both pointers point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 2):

Because malloc addresses are 16-byte aligned by default on your platform. And new just uses malloc.

The result can highly depends on the used platform and the malloc implementation on your system. But most systems will print 16.

Answer (score 2):

Because of INTERNAL compiler behaviour. It MAY allocate next memory block just after previous one.

But this is completely realisation option. Compiler MAY stop doing so EVERY MOMENT.

By the way, my compiler (gcc on ubuntu) prints 32

```
0x12b2010
0x12b2030
32
```

Answer (score 2):

possibly due to alignment, but also the fact that every memory-chunk allocated with new or malloc have to remember its own size, and thus is larger than what you requested. the 'extra' info is usually right before the pointer returned